# How can I fix this error at make from Azerothcore?

Tags: c++, azerothcore

I am installing it by using the Documentation from Azerothcore, and at the point where I use the command "make" there came the following error:

```
/home/wowazerothcore/azerothcore/src/server/scripts/Northrend/DraktharonKeep/boss_novos.cpp:57:65: fatal error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'const std::unordered_map<uint32, std::tuple<uint32, Position> >'
std::unordered_map<uint32, std::tuple <uint32, Position>> const npcSummon =
                                                                ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:139:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: cannot convert initializer list argument to 'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long')
      unordered_map(size_type __n = 10,
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:214:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'Misc' to
      'std::pair<const unsigned int, std::tuple<unsigned int, Position> >' for 1st argument
      unordered_map(initializer_list<value_type> __l,
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:160:2: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_InputIterator'
        unordered_map(_InputIterator __f, _InputIterator __l,
        ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:188:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
      unordered_map(const unordered_map& __umap,
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:198:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
      unordered_map(unordered_map&& __umap,
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:169:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 3 were provided
      unordered_map(const unordered_map&) = default;
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:172:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires 1 argument, but 3 were provided
      unordered_map(unordered_map&&) = default;
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../../include/c++/4.9/bits/unordered_map.h:179:7: note: candidate constructor not viable: requires single argument '__a', but 3 arguments were provided
      unordered_map(const allocator_type& __a)
      ^
1 error generated.
src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/build.make:13452: recipe for target 'src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/Northrend/DraktharonKeep/boss_novos.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/Northrend/DraktharonKeep/boss_novos.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1558: recipe for target 'src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/server/scripts/CMakeFiles/scripts.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I fix this error?

the "git log" command have the following first line:

wowazerothcore@rs000165:~/azerothcore$ git log

commit 2bb868164e545d38da5c96a3ce683a5fcb3b72a6

gcc version is

wowazerothcore@rs000165:~/azerothcore$ gcc --version

gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10+deb8u2) 4.9.2

Comment: Can you please add the first line of output from command `git log` when run from dir /home/wowazerothcore/azerothcore to your question?

Comment: Also the output of `gcc --version`

Comment: also did you do any changes to the source? can you please give more details about your system?

Comment: Could you try updating gcc please?

Comment: @MishaP to which Version, because my Debian system says at "apt update" all packages are up to date

Comment: please paste output of `lsb_release -a` command

Comment: root@rs000165:~# lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.

Distributor ID: Debian

Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie)

Release:        8.11

Codename:       jessie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the reason for the error you are seeing is an old version of gcc, because the compiler is pointing to gcc include files.

The reason apt-get update is showing all packages up to date, is because

> Debian GNU/Linux 8.11 (jessie) Release: 8.11 Codename: jessie

is an old version of Debian. As per Debian package search:
https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=gcc

> Package gcc
>   jessie (oldoldstable) (devel): GNU C compiler
>   4:4.9.2-2: amd64 armel armhf i386
>   stretch (oldstable) (devel): GNU C compiler
>   4:6.3.0-4: amd64 arm64 armel armhf i386 mips mips64el mipsel ppc64el s390x
>   buster (stable) (devel): GNU C compiler
>   4:8.3.0-1: amd64 arm64 armel armhf i386 mips mips64el mipsel ppc64el s390x

4.9 is the highest supported stable version of gcc on your system.

**Proposed solutions:**

1) Upgrade from Debian 8 (jessie) to Debian 9 (stretch) or Debian 10 (buster)
instructions here: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-upgrade-debian-8-jessie-to-debian-9-stretch

2) Add testing repo to your apt-repos, pin the higher version of gcc, apt-update and install the higher version of gcc from the testing repo. Instructions here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/284817/how-to-install-gcc-5-on-debian-jessie-8-1

The first option might carry some risks, so I advise you to back up your data, just in case.

The second option is basically using packages that don't have priority support from the Debian group, so your milage may vary.